# vb.net clear multi-key dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I am writing a program to populate a .txt template file with values by replacing placeholders. The values are coming from an excel document.
I am reading a map file that contains, line by line 3 values; a subheader in excel, the element name and the placeholder. these values are being placed into 3 arrays and then combined into a multi-key dictionary.

I want to be able to run the program several times without having to close it, So i need to clear the dictionary after it is finished running so i can run it again. I have been unable to clear using .clear() and not sure why.
It works when I clear it and then list the content in the same sub but not when I clear it in one sub and then try to use it in another.
I am declaring the dictionary at the class level and using it in multiple subs/functions.

```
'Dictionary
Dim ObjDict As New Dictionary(Of ObjKey, String)

Structure ObjKey
    Public CIQ_Obj_Key As String
    Public CIQ_Sec_Key As String
    Public YAML_Tag_Key As String
End Structure
```

This is how I have been populating the dictionary

```
Do Until xx = RowUpperBound

    If xlWorkSheet.Cells(xx, ObjHeaderColInt).Value = CIQ_Obj_Txt Then
        'MsgBox("Found " & CIQ_Obj_Txt & " in row " & xx)
        XlCell = CType(xlWorkSheet.Cells(xx, ValHeaderColInt), excel.Range)
        If IsNothing(XlCell.Value2) Then
            Write_Error_("No value found for " & CIQ_Obj_Txt & " at row " & xx)
        Else
            CellStr = XlCell.Value2.ToString.Trim
            TxtBxDebugBox.Text += "Found " & CIQ_Obj_Txt & ": " & CellStr & " at " & xx & vbNewLine
            GlobalVariables.ObjDict.Add(New GlobalVariables.ObjKey() With {.CIQ_Obj_Key = CIQ_Obj_Txt,
                                                                      .CIQ_Sec_Key = CIQ_Sec_Txt,
                                                                     .YAML_Tag_Key = YAML_Tag_Txt}, CellStr)
        End If
            Exit Do
    ElseIf xx = (RowUpperBound - 1) Then
            Write_Error_("Cannot find " & CIQ_Obj_Txt & " under " & CIQ_Sec_Txt)
            Exit Do
    End If
        xx += 1
Loop
```

I recently tried declaring it in a seperate Class but do not know how to clear/close the Class and then re-declare it.

```
Public Class GlobalVariables
Public Shared ObjDict As New Dictionary(Of ObjKey, String)

Structure ObjKey
    Public CIQ_Obj_Key As String
    Public CIQ_Sec_Key As String
    Public YAML_Tag_Key As String
End Structure

End Class
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You say it doesn't work when you try and use the dictionary from a different method... What exactly do you mean by doesn't work? Exception details please... Failing everything, objDict.DIspose() followed by objDict = New DIctionary(of ObkKey, String) should do the job...

Comment: @MartinMilan, your would think so wouldn't you. But for some reason known only to Microsoft... dictionaries have no Dispose method.

Comment: What exception are you getting? What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WHen using a class like that it's best to add iDisposable support.

And do not use shared.... it makes the data shared over all instances.

```
Private GB as GlobalVatiables

Public Class GlobalVariables
    Implements IDisposable

    Public ObjDict As New Dictionary(Of ObjKey, String)

    Structure ObjKey
        Public CIQ_Obj_Key As String
        Public CIQ_Sec_Key As String
        Public YAML_Tag_Key As String
    End Structure

    Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls

    ' IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                ' TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
                ObjDict.Clear()
                ObjDict = Nothing
            End If

            ' TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override Finalize() below.
            ' TODO: set large fields to null.
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    ' TODO: override Finalize() only if Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    'Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    '    ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above.
    '    Dispose(False)
    '    MyBase.Finalize()
    'End Sub

    ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

When you are done with it simple call the dispose method

```
GB.Dispose
```